# Can't limit FPS OpenGL and C

Tags: c, opengl, frame-rate, game-development

I'm writing my own OpenGL and Win32 library in C, and I'm implementing a function to limit FPS. To do that, I'm firstly writing some code to check if it works and then I will abstract it to functions later.
I don't know what's missing but it's not working. Here's my current code and the output

```
#include "2DM.h"
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {

   WINDOW window = createWindow("WINDOW", 500, 500, WINDOW_NORMAL);

   const int FPS_LIMIT = 60;
   int initialTime = time(NULL), finalTime, frameCount = 0;
   
   while(window.open) {

       if(pollEvents(&window) {

           /*
            * Events handling
            * .........
            */
       }

       /*
        * OpenGL code
        * .........
        */

       display(&window);

       frameCount ++;
       finalTime = time(NULL);
       int ellapsedTime = finalTime - initialTime;

       if(ellapsedTime) {

           int fps = frameCount / ellapsedTime;
           int sleepMs = (1000 / FPS_LIMIT) - ellapsedTime;
           printf("FPS: %i\nMS to Sleep: %i\n", fps, sleepMs);

           frameCount = 0;
           initialTime = finalTime;

           Sleep(sleepMs);
       }

   }
}
```

The output I get is: FPS:

```
FPS: 5749
MS to Sleep: 15
```

Comment: there is no language called C/C++. If you a writing C code then the C++ tag is irrelevant. If you are using the C library in C++ you should clarify

Answer (score 1):

`time()` returns the time in integer seconds, which won't work for what you are trying to do.

For instance, at the moment, you only get into the `if` once every second or so. `sleepMs` is also wrong, since you are subtracting different units.

Comment: As I need milliseconds, I've multiplied ellapsedTime by 1000, like this: int sleepMs = (1000 / FPS_LIMIT) - ellapsedTime * 1000; but still not working :(

Comment: That is not the only thing you will have to fix, please read the answer again :)

Comment: @MorcilloSanz You understand `ellapsedTime` will be 0 almost every frame, right? If your app runs at 60 FPS,`time(NULL)` will return the same value as the previous frame 59 out of 60 times,

Comment: @lvella Even worse: once every 5749 frames, according to the output OP is showing!